# linq how to query a specific date's data

Tags: linq

I'm using Linq querying today's date. There is one column in my table called `VisitTime` which is a `Datetime` type.

I want to know how to write query statement to search today's data. Can anyone help me on this?

```
WebStatDataContext dc = new WebStatDataContext(_connString);

var query=
    from v in dc. VisitorInfors
    where v.VisitTime......
    select v
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `DateTime.Now`, you should always store it in a local variable otherwise you can get really nasty bugs from the clock changing between calls:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var query = from v in dc.VisitorInfors
            where v.VisitTime.Date == now.Date
            select v;
```

Comment: Why it says it does not contain a definition for 'Date'?

Comment: What says it does not contain a definition for `Date`?

Comment: I asked _what_ says it does not contain a definition for `Date`, not which use of `Date` does something claim there is no definition for.

Comment: @Steven Zack: What is the type of `VisitorInfors.VisitTime`?

Comment: DateTime. It works if you convert it to DateTime before using Date property. E.G ((DateTime)v.VisitTime).Date == now.Date BTW, thanks for your help.

Comment: If `VisitorInfors.VisitTime` is an instance of `DateTime` you should not need to cast it to access the property `DateTime.Date`.

Comment: In this statement, have to cast first, otherwise, VisualStudio will report error.

Comment: If VisitTime is nullable, you might have to use ... where v.VisitTime.Value.Date == now.Date

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.Now` :

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var query =    
    from v in dc. VisitorInfors    
    where v.VisitTime == currentDate.Date
    select v;
```